# Shabbat Belt - is 2 belts acceptable under the following circumstances

Tags: halacha, shabbat, hotzaa-carrying-reshuyot

A Chabad rabbi told me that even though I wear a normal belt, I can wear a secondary shabbos belt in the following way. I grab the back 2 tzitzit and bring them around and over the front 2 tzitzit and then use the secondary shabbos belt to hold them in place. I was under the impression the function of the shabbos belt had to perform what would be considered a normal everyday function. I don't normally wear my back tzitzit over my front and thats why I am confused as to why he said it was acceptable. Anyone have an opinion on such a ruling?

Comment: This is a machlokes between ashkanazim and sefardim

Comment: I suspect what the Chabad Rabbi was trying to convey to you was to use the 2nd belt in the capacity of preventing the beged of your tzitzit from bunching up. Most Lubavitcher’s wear a tallit katan that is actually big enough to cover the majority of their body if kept flat. In that capacity it can even be used for atifah and is considered to be a hiddur.

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) DI and thanks for this first question. Can I recommend you take the [tour](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/tour) to get a sense of how the site works?  Great to have you learn with us!

Answer (score 5):

See [Shulchan Aruch HaRav Orech Chaim 301:42](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/3775896/jewish/Shulchan-Aruch-Chapter-301-Articles-Which-One-May-Go-Out-to-the-Public-Domain-While-Wearing-and-Those-Which-Are-Forbidden-To-Be-Worn.htm#v42), at the end of the halacha. There, it is explained that one may wear two belts if each one is accomplishing something, and the wearer therefore derives benefit and satisfaction from it.

Without being able to read your rabbi's mind, it appears that he was telling you that if you use the secondary shabbat belt to hold your tzizit in place, than you are using it to accomplish something that your primary belt is not. Therefore, it would be permissible.

Comment: Ok thanks for reply